# What is the R function in the tidyverse package which allows you add some characters to the start/end a string?

Tags: r, stringr

(Please note that I am new to coding/r programming so I'm finding this a bit difficult.)

For example, I have a simple dataset of students and their respective weights.

```
Class <- c("Tom", "Ana", "John", "Sara")
Weight <- c(50, 45, 52, 47)
df <- data.frame(Class, Weight)
```

How can I add the "kg" unit to the end of each weight in the "Weight" variable, without having to manually type it in?

(I think this can be done using the stringr package but I'm not sure.)

Many thanks,
Karima

Comment: You can just use `paste0`: `df %>% mutate(Weight = paste0(Weight, "kg"))`

Comment: `paste(Weight, "kg")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste0` from base R (nice if you don't want dependencies), or [`stringr::str_c`](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_c.html) (fits in well if you're using lots of other `stringr` functions). While some `stringr` functions offer advantages over their base counterparts, this pair is essentially identical.

```
df %>% mutate(Weight = str_c(Weight, "kg"))
```

For reference, you can see this is equivalent to `paste0`:

```
assertthat::are_equal(
  df %>% mutate(Weight = str_c(Weight, "kg")),
  df %>% mutate(Weight = paste0(Weight, "kg"))
) # TRUE
```

Comment: @GregorThomas, that's a fair request, although in truth I mainly just expanded on my comment to OP because a `stringr`/`tidyverse` solution was specifically requested.  Practically I use `paste` and `str_c` interchangeably - and the `str_c` docs note: "paste() for equivalent base R functionality."  If you'd like to offer additional thoughts, I'd welcome an edit.

Comment: @Karima, if this answered your question, please mark it answered by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.  That will let others know your problem has been successfully resolved.